What are the words for Eternal in the Bible?
I have heard that aidios is the only word for eternal and all others are only referring to age (an ending period of time). (Possible source link added)
In the Bible Aidios is used only twice in Romans 1:20 and Jude 1:6-7.
There are several other words, but I'm not familiar with them.
Can someone please give me an short overview of the various words for Eternal, age, and similar? I am primarily interested in the true words for "eternal" and not "age".

Hebrew scripture expresses the limited concept of a long time. The Greek scriptures speak of the 'ages' αἰών . English expresses 'everlasting' (having a beginning in time but enduring beyond the end of time) and 'eternal' ( an eternal state other than time). Could you be more precise about your line of enquiry as this is quite an extensive subject. And it should be remembered that it is only through the appearing of our Saviour Jesus Christ, who hath abolished death which has brought life and immortality to light through the gospel:

"I have heard that aidios is …".  The question should include an explicit quotation and cite the source.

Submitted an rewrite of the question for the OP.

The Hebrew concept which is attempting to be expressed by a few different words in Greek is that of "to the horizon, and again".  That is to say, the vanishing point.  It can be applied backward along the timeline, forward along the timeline, or both as when expressing the duration or age of God (from everlasting to everlasting).


qeḏem -  Deuteronomy 33:27 KJV - The eternal (qeḏem) God is thy refuge, and underneath are the everlasting arms: and he shall thrust out the enemy from before thee; and shall say, Destroy them.

aidios - Romans 1:20 KJV - For the invisible things of him from the creation of the world are clearly seen, being understood by the things that are made, even his eternal (aidios) power and Godhead; so that they are without excuse.

aiōniou - Mark 3:29 KJV - But he that shall blaspheme against the Holy Ghost hath never forgiveness, but is in danger of eternal (aiōniou) damnation.

olam - Genesis 3:22 KJV - And the Lord God said, Behold, the man is become as one of us, to know good and evil: and now, lest he put forth his hand, and take also of the tree of life, and eat, and live forever (olam).



You should add in olam as in Genesis 3:22, "...and live forever."

Thank you! I have edited my answer to include olam
